# DynamicResource only for one binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I create style. This Style create arrow for navigation

```html
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="navigation_arrow">
    <Setter Property="Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <DockPanel.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                </DockPanel.LayoutTransform>
                <Grid>
                <Canvas>
                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <Rectangle Fill="LightBlue" Width="24" Height="6" Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="30.277"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="-0.79314" Y="-2.18035"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle Fill="LightBlue" Width="44" Height="6" Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="-1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
                    <Polygon Fill="LightBlue" Points="0,12, 12,12, 6,1.6" Canvas.Left="-7" Canvas.Top="-4" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.5">
                        <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-89.8"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="5.97906" Y="5.99996"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Polygon.RenderTransform>

                    </Polygon>
                    <Rectangle Fill="LightBlue" Width="24" Height="6" Canvas.Left="-1" Canvas.Top="2" RenderTransformOrigin="1,0">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-30.277"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="-4.00853" Y="-14.1804"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then I set this style to MenuItem

```html
<MenuItem Style="{DynamicResource navigation_arrow}" Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseBack" />
<MenuItem Style="{DynamicResource navigation_arrow}" Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseForward" />
```

And I see that the first MenuItem lost hist style and became empty. But second MenuItem apply this style. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Your bug is not related to DynamicResource binding. ofcourse it should work for few items.
I think your bug is somewhere else. Try to add more MenuItems, change to other DynamicResource style, etc. Share it so we can help you with this!

Comment: post an image showing the result .

Comment: Please add some more details of your style. How does the real control template look like (without ...)?

Comment: It is style for Navigation(Back and Forward)
I create Style with DynamicResource for several Buttons and all works good. But in this case I dont uderstend why it is dont work!

Comment: The problem is that the value, in your case the DockPanel and its content, is only created once even if the style is used more often. Because the DockPanel is a UIElement it can only be used and displayed once. In other words each Icon gets the same instance of UIElement assigned and only the last usage can display it. I'm still not sure whether there is a good solution for that.

Comment: Just a small side note. This path creates exactly the same arrow as your DockPanel et al (of course it doesn't solve the main problem): `<Path Data="M0,6 L23,6 M10.3,0 L0,6 10.3,12"         Stroke="LightBlue" StrokeThickness="2.7" />`

Comment: may have some sort of an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I see right now, add `x:Shared="False"`

```
    <Style x:Key="navigation_arrow"
           TargetType="Button"
           x:Shared="False">
     ...
```

to your style.